# JPA:EclipselInk: Invalid object while persisting

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am creating a Author Entity and trying to persist, getting the ivalid object database exception.
Here is my code.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "AuthDetails")
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    protected Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    
    @Transient
    private Integer age;
    
    Author() {
    
    }
    
    Author(String firstName, String lastName, LocalDate dateOfBirth) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }
}
```

Persistence.xml i have defined the Author.
I am calling as below:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("bookPU");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();

        tx.begin();
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(1984, 04, 23);
        em.persist(new Author("ABC","XYZ",date));
        tx.commit();
```

Getting exception as below:
nternal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'AuthDetails'.
Error Code: 208
Call: INSERT INTO AuthDetails (ID, DATEOFBIRTH, FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
bind => [4 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(lok.learning.jpademo.callback.Author@2c991465)
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.6.v20200131-b7c997804f): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'AuthDetails'.
Error Code: 208

Any help

Comment: Does the table "AuthDetails" exist? Error suggests it doesn't.

Comment: No it does not exist. I believe the JPA persist query should create automatically right

Comment: No, table creation is a feature you enable. See https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/DDL or with JPA https://thorben-janssen.com/standardized-schema-generation-data-loading-jpa-2-1/